# Showing a sequence from a metric space is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to show that a sequence $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. I have already shown that $d(x_m,x_n)=m^{-1}-n^{-1}$ when $m<n$. So I just have to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that $m^{-1}-n^{-1}<\epsilon$ for $m,n>N$. I know this should be very simple but I can not see how to do it.

If I pick an arbitrary positive $\epsilon$ how to I choose an appropriate $N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $N > 0$ such that $\frac{2}{N} < \varepsilon$. Then, if $n,m > N$, you have

$$ \left| \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n} \right| \leq \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} < \frac{2}{N} < \varepsilon. $$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\left\lvert\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}\right\lvert\leq\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{2}{n}$$
where $m\geq n$.